# How does Youtube display ads on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube, jwplayer, meta-tags

I'm using jwplayer to embed videos to my website and facebook page, but the pre roll ads don't show on facebook, but they do with youtube player.

Comment: I think YouTube and Facebook have some sort of partnership to allow for this.